# Grammaticality of "I have a car, neither does Sara"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, conjunctions, negation

Can we say "I have a red car. Neither does Sara." or must we say "I have a red car but Sara doesn't."?

I have read this on a website and they said that the first sentence is incorrect but I don't think the same so I need your help.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is incorrect.

*Neither* **is** a negative word, but it can't be used except with another negative constituent. Usually the other negative constituent is marked with *nor*.

- *They serve neither beer nor wine here.* (They don't serve beer **and** don't serve wine either.)
- *I don't have a red car. Neither does Sarah.* (I don't have one **and** Sarah doesn't, either)

  > (For the reasons why this is so, see [De Morgan's Laws](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/logicguide.pdf).)

In other words, you can't use *neither* **alone** to negate something.

Affirmatives have more options:

- *I have a red car. So does Sarah.*
- *I have a red car. Sarah does, too.*
- *Sarah and I both have a red car/red cars.*

etc.

Comment: Possibly too sweeping. *They serve beer nor wine here* is archaic/affected, but not wrong.

Comment: Perhaps in the UK. There are phrases like _kith nor kin_, but they almost always are NPIs and require a triggering negative.

Comment: @TimLymington that doesn't necessarily go against what John wrote here, though I would still say that your example stretches the *nor* enough to leave a mark.

Comment: @JonHanna: against the spirit, though not the letter. And 'rare' is not 'overstretched'; the OED has a 2007 citation (*three times before in my career... I, nor my management, have ever had any kind of problem with creating a gay character*).

Comment: Yes, it does get used, but it's highly formulaic language and meant to have a particular effect. It's not anything one should point out to an EFL learner, for sure. If you look through **all** the quotations in the OED, you're sure to find just about everything.

Comment: @TimLymington. That example doesn't switch negation partway through. *Nor* is stretched in "They serve beer nor wine" because it's both re-casting what came before into a negative, and as well as telling us what follows is negative. "I, nor my management, have ever..." has less pressure put upon it. That's what I mean by stretched. It may well be valid, but even if it wasn't rare, words should be stretched with care.

Comment: Just wanted to note that there are cases when "neither" can stand without "nor" or any other negation. At the moment, the only cases I can think of require both that "neither" modify a noun and that the context of use be one in which there are a pair of things / people / individuals or groups which are described by that noun. For example, there might be a law concerning marriage that states, "Neither spouse-to-be may be married to any other persons at the time the marriage application is filed".

Answer (score 2):

Let's get the other uses of *neither* down for completeness, before focusing on this use, because it does help to think about all the ways it is used.

As a determiner or a pronoun, it rejects all of two or more possibilities.*

> "Would you like the chocolate or the coffee cake?" "Neither, thanks."
>
> The EL&U question asked which of two sentences was correct, but neither seemed correct to me.

Along with *nor* as a conjunction:

> That is fit for neither man nor beast!

Now, onto the conjunctive adverb sense you're looking at. Just as the other senses are negating all of a set of possibilities, so as an adverb it means not just that the case is not so, but that it is **comparably** not so.

> I don't have a car, and neither does Sarah.
>
> I don't have a car. Neither does Sarah.

If you are not making a negative statement in **both** cases, then *neither* is not appropriate.

> I have a car, so does Sarah.
>
> I have a car. Sarah does not.
>
> I don't have a car, but Sarah does.

*While there is a long standing use of *neither* for more than two items, some say it should only be used for two items, with "none of" or similar for three or more. Certainly, "none  of" seems better to me sometimes, but *neither* seems fine other times.

Comment: "None of snow, rain, heat, or gloom of night stays these courageous couriers from the swift completion of their appointed rounds" just doesn't have the same ring, does it?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Or Kipling's "The Ballad of East and West": "But there is neither East nor West, Border, nor Breed, nor Birth, / When two strong men stand face to face, though they come from the ends of the earth!" Ironically, I think some of the strength of these comes from the fact that *neither* is often taken to refer to only two items; with the third and subsequent it piles on more than we've been led to expect.